# Cleaning up my View with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The snippet I would like to change is the following:

`<p>You have <span ng-model="char-count">{{255 - (name.length + email.length + textarea.length)}}</span> characters left</p>`

Where `255 - name.length + email.length + textarea.length` could be wrap up in a function, but when I try to do this in the controller, it is not working. I might just not be understanding a core concept here. Link to my full codepen can be found here: http://codepen.io/Travo100/pen/pvRyoa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the answers, defining a function on the scope and calling it on the binding expression solves the problem. But I would like to point some other options that you might consider.

- [Binding to the left function](http://codepen.io/thiagofelix/pen/yygoWp): Take a look on your console to see how many times the function is called, even when you are doing nothing that should trigger the computation of characters. [It affects Angular dirty check performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961940/angularjs-dirty-checking-performace)
- [Binding to a pre computed property](http://codepen.io/thiagofelix/pen/dPNzEB): Instead of put a function call on your expression like the option above, you can listen to the variables that matter for the characters left, and automatically compute again whatever they change, having always an updated value.

  `$scope.$watch('[name,email,textarea]', function (values) {
     $scope.count = 255;
     angular.forEach(values, function (val) {
       $scope.count -= val? val.length : 0;
     })
  }, true);`
- [Create a filter](http://codepen.io/thiagofelix/pen/QwdqWM): Move the computation from the controller into an specific filter which receives the string to be measured and the max number of character:

  **html**

  `<span ng-bind="name + email + textarea | cl:255"></span>`

  **javascript**

  `angular.module('contact', [])
  .filter('cl', function () {
    return function (input, size) {
      input = input || '';
      return size - input.length;
    }
  })`

**Conclusion**

So, trying to help you with *Cleaning up my View with AngularJS* and give you some sort of answer. As you can see there are some options that you should consider and trade off which one is more appropriate. I personally would try to stick with the 3th options which uses an filter because it is more flexible and can be reused in any other view that you have.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give me other options to consider! This answer is the best by far! Anywhere in particular you have gotten your knowledge of angularJS from?

Comment: You welcome. I didn't learn from book or course, so I wouldn't recommend any of these. Take a look on github projects using angular, read their code base, try to get your hands dirty, you will start to see patterns after practicing several times. Also learn the official documentation from head to tail, it is the best resource IMO.

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.left = 255 - $scope.name.length - $scope.email.length - $scope.textarea.length;
```

then

```
<p>You have <span> {{left}} </span> characters left</p>
```

Comment: That is not working when I put the $scope.left expression in the controller.

Comment: Assign $scope.left once doesn't make it keep changing as the email, name, and the text area changes. Loosing its bindable requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your controller

```
$scope.left = function(){
    var totalLength = 255;
    if($scope.name){
        totalLength -= $scope.name.length;
    }

    if($scope.email){
        totalLength -= $scope.email.length;
    }

    if($scope.textarea){
        totalLength -= $scope.textarea.length;
    }

    return totalLength;
};
```

Add this to render the output of the function in your HTML.

```
<p>You have <span> {{left()}} </span> characters left</p>
```

Comment: Although it works, you should be careful of using function calls on the binding expressions, like {{left()}} because angular will evaluate the expression (call the function) several times, even when you are doing nothing that should trigger the computation of characters left again. Thus wasting computation resource.